# Continuous Form populate textbox to another form

Tags: forms, textbox, continuous

so I have made a form with two combo boxes which are filtering a query for a match.
This works great. But now i want to add a search engine. Since there are different matches depending on the release date of the item I am planning to let the user select the required data from a continuous form. Depending on this selection i want to populate the textbox to the first form and into the combo box. I hope you can understand it. [I hope this fast pic will help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE3Un.png)
I tried it with the code:

```
Private Sub Übernehmen_Button_Click()
Forms!MainForm!Search = Me!textboxform2
End Sub
```

But it does not work. Also if i add a MsgBox to the code, it wont show as long as the code above is written. As soon as i remove the code above, the msgbox shows by pressing the button.....
I also tried it with .value or [ ] around the single parts ( [textboxform2] but nothing works. It DOES work on the same sheet, and the following code also works but i do not know why it does not work with the first code and why the msg box stops working aswell.

```
Private Sub Open_Form()
Forms![MainForm]![SU_PMS] = [SearchEngineForm2]
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... The code is

Private Sub Verwenden_Button_Click()

Forms!Mainform!Search = Me!textboxform2

Forms!Mainform.Requery

DoCmd.Close

End Sub